# preg_match, find and extract

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using this to determine if a string looks like the right url, and then extract a value

```
if (preg_match('#^(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?site.com\/cat\/(aaa\d{5,30})\/#', $url, $urlid)) {

   echo $urlid[3];

}
```

It works ok, but I think it could be more lean/improved (or just more good-practice). Should I add some "negative look-ahead", "non-capturing" or other?

This for example `(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?` was just a quick thought. It works, but... Should it really be in parentheses or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you looked into [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: Preg_match is already very fast. Your regex can't really be made faster and unless you are doing a 1 million loop of that code, does it really matter to optimize this and gain 0.0001s?

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin I'm not so much after optimizing speed.. it's more "am I doing it right"? ;)

Comment: @mowgli There are millions of ways to do something right in PHP, Parse_URL is one, preg_match is another. Both are truly fine!

Comment: I mean MY code, not preg_match in general..

Comment: You don't need to escape your forward slashes if you're not using them as delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
if (preg_match('~^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?site\.com/cat/(aaa\d{5,30})/~', $url, $urlid))
    echo $urlid[1];
```

Improvements:

- no need to use capturing groups when you don't need to capture something, use a non-capturing group instead `(?:...)`
- no need to escape `/` when it is not used as delimiter
- you need to escape `.` otherwise it is not seen as a literal character

Benefits:

- the pattern is no more ambigous since `\.` matches a dot and not an other character
- it's a little more readable since there is no more useless backslashes
- a small memory/speed gain with the use of non-capturing groups

Comment: ... and whats the benefit of doing so?